# Overlaying with CSS

Tags: css, layout

I want to load a website in an iframe, and overlay the website with some hints about the website that is shown. However, i got stuck at the point that the website has a variable passive white space at the left and right site (just like in stackoverflow).

This means that i cannot position the overlays absolute or relative to the div the iframe is located in.

How can i make sure that the overlays are on the same places across browsers and across different screen resolutions?

Nobody has an answer? Or is my question not clear?

Comment: The answers were not what i was looking for, but i fixed it already. Thnx anyway

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
body{ 
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position it to the `<body>`.

Comment: Explain yourself, im not very familiar with css